# C++ - Adding a list<Task> l (or any STL Container) as a data member is causing an error, when deleting an array of tasks allocated on heap

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, pointers

I've got a class called Task. The header file goes as such:

```
class Task
{
public:
    Task();
//Methods Declarations

private:

int uid;
list<Task> l;

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Task &t);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const list<Task *> &l);
};
```

Now in my main file, I run:

```
Task * tasks[7];
for (int i = 0; i != 7; ++i)
    tasks[i] = new Task();

delete [] *tasks;
```

upon running `delete[] *tasks;` I get the error message below:

```
Assignment 4(23901) malloc: *** error for object 0x1001009f8: pointer being 
                                freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in 
                                malloc_error_break to debug
```

As soon as I comment out `list < Task *> l`, and re-run it, the error message goes away. I tried changing `list < Task * > l`, to `list < Task > l`, but to no avail.

I can't figure it out. Why would it error out, when `list < Task >` is allocated on the stack (well pointers to heap elements)? (STL management). Also tried `vector<int>`. I get the same thing.

UPDATE: delete tasks[i] didn't do the trick.

Comment: Did you try defining a ~Task() {} and then using for ... delete tasks[i]? Sounds weird, but just to rule awkward compiler bugs.

Comment: yup, originally it was a list < Task * > l; so I had to have a destructor. then tried an empty one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use

```
delete [] *tasks;
```

but

```
for (int i = 0; i != 7; ++i)
    delete tasks[i];
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, deleting them individually didn't delete anything.

Comment: because I printed values individually, only the first element was deleted. By deleted, the internal uid value changed, but the rest remained as they were.

Comment: @macguy: `delete`ing them just makes the memory reusable, the deleted contents may/may not be necessarily removed(depending on implementations) from the memory location.However, accessing the elements after you `delete` them is an **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: And I also tried the above with integers. Look:

int * zabre_kbir[10];
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        zabre_kbir[i] = new int(i);
    }
    delete [] *zabre_kbir; //works
//individual deletion doesn't

Comment: Thx Als, so I should just take it, that delete tasks[i], does the trick, even though the memory values are still there?

Comment: @macguy as Als said, you shouldn't expect the values to be cleared. The memory is just marked as deleted. Try allocating something new, the memory could be reused. Or use a memory profiler to see if the memory is really deleted.

Comment: @macguy: As long as for every address returned by `new` and `new[]` You have a corresponding `delete` and `delete []` being called on the same address, You don't have any memory leaks.

Comment: ok, I'll just try to check for any memory leak. C++ is not my native language, Java is, and a fair amount of Objective-C (higher level)

Comment: I just had one more question: Why would it error out as soon as I introduce an STL container?

Comment: @macguy since the syntax is wrong, it's most probably undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including an error.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Is there any Private Messaging system on here?

Comment: @macguy there's a chat, but you don't have enough reputation to use it. You need 20 rep.

Comment: @macguy if you want the memory to be cleared superseed the type and set it to "0" in the destructor, if you build an application which requires you to carry sensitive data you might want to use mlock or mlockall to make sure no memory gets paged out (if it pages sensitive blocks you will have those in the swap, mlock will prevent the swapping out)

Comment: Thanks, That was one of the things I was looking for, I could easily have a destructor that changes the internal value to a negative, seeing how all values are positive. I'll keep the mlock thing in mind for future reference, luckily this isn't really data-sensitive, so I don't have to wrap my head around it much.